# NGUI sprites become blurry on android

Tags: unity, hud, ngui

I have this screen in the editor made with NGUI and 8 sprites:

[image]

But when I build it for android and open the game the same sprites on the screen looks blurry

[image]

I don't know what could be causing this, I have all the sprites in Point(no filter) mode, no mip maps and in True Color. Their Max Size is according to each sprite size.

I haven't touched anything strange in the atlas maker(it's only one big atlas), so it should have all default settings. What could possible be the cause of this? I have been searching but I haven't found anyone who had the same problem. Is there a setting I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by going into the Atlas texture made by NGUI and unchecking the option of "Generate Mip Maps"